# Find the eigenspace for this vector space defined on the real-sequnces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let the vector space $V$ be a set of the real sequences. Defining the operation $\{a_n + b_n\} = \{a_n\}+\{b_n\}$ and $c\{a_n\}=ca_n$ (Here $\langle{a_n}\rangle$,$\langle{b_n}\rangle \in V$ ,   $c \in\mathbb{R}$). Say subspace of the $V$, $W $ is a set of sequences whose elements satisfying $a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}+3a_{n}=0$.

$B$(Set of the basis of the $W$) = $\{u_1,u_2\}$. (Here the $u_1 = (1,0,-3,-15,-66,...)$ and $u_2 = (0,1,5,22,95,....)$)

Defining the Linear mapping $T : W\to W$ by $T(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,...) = (a_2, a_3, a_4,...)$.

Find the Eigenspace for the $T$.

I found matrix like the below  since $T(u_1)= -3u_2, T(u_2) = u_1 + 5u_2$$$A = [T]_B =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
-3 & 5  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Eigenvalue is $\frac{5\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$. From now I'll take the just $\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ case.

Therefore Eigenvector is $[V]_B =\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{5+\sqrt{13}} \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $ for the Eigenvalue, $\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}$. Coneseqently my answer is $\langle \frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}u_1 + u_2\rangle$(Eigenspace of the $\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}$)

But the exercise in my book suggests Eigenspace of the $\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ be  $\{({\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2})}^{n-1} \alpha \vert \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

I can't understand why the answer should be. In my thought, The eigenspace must be subset of the $V$. But Following the my book's suggestion, The $\{({\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2})}^{n-1} \alpha \vert \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ does not the subset of the $V$ at all. Is my things right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $a_{n+2} - 5 a_{n+1} + 3 a_n = 0$  we get

$a_n = A r_1^{n-1} + B r_2^{n-1} $

where $r_{1,2} = \dfrac{ 5 \pm \sqrt{13} }{2} $

Since $T( a_n ) = a_{n+1} $, then

$T(a_n) = A r_1^n + B r_2^n $

If $T(a_n) = \lambda a_n $, then

$ A r_1^{n} + B r_2^{n} = \lambda ( A r_1^{n-1} + B r_2^{n-1} ) $

which is satisfied if $B = 0$ and $\lambda = r_1$  or $A = 0$ and $\lambda = r_2 $

You're interested in the first case, so the associated eigenvector is

$a_n = A \left(\dfrac{5 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right)^{n-1} $